# Anagram Substring Search

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

I am having difficulty understanding the runtime and space complexity while implementing the said question.

Following is the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AnagaramInBigString {


private static Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap(String str)
{
    Map<Character, Integer> source = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {

        if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {

            if(source.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))

            {
                source.put(str.charAt(i), source.get(str.charAt(i) + 1));
            }
            else source.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }

    return source;
}


public static void main(String []args)
{
    String check= "BACDGABCDA";
    String sample = "ABCD";
    System.out.println(sample.length());

    for(int i= 0; i <= check.length() - sample.length() ; i++)
    {
        String checkSub = check.substring(i, i + sample.length());
        System.out.println(checkSub);
        System.out.println(frequencyMap(checkSub).equals(frequencyMap(sample)));
    }
}


}
```

Is the time complexity `O(check*sample)`? Space complexity is `O(sample)`?
Also please suggest on how I can improve the efficiency of this code.

Like:

1. I can calculate the hashmap for sample string only once instead of doing it again and again with every iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time and space complexity is usually represented with `n` and `m`, so `O(check*sample)` and `O(sample)` would be `O(nm)` and `O(n)`.

For complexity, if `m` is sample, and `n` is check, time complexity is actually `O(n(n-m))`, or \$O(n^2 - m)\$, which I would say is simple `O(n)`. Same with space complexity, as well (this I am not sure about, please correct me if I am incorrect).

---

Also, you have:

```
public class AnagaramInBigString {
```

and:

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap(String str)
{
```

One word to describe this: inconsistency. Be consistent. Either have a newline, or don't.

I suggest not have a new line, as it wastes newlines, and doesn't it make it a bit more readable. It also follows Java conventions.

This crazy code:

> ```
>     if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
>     {
>         continue;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>
>         if(source.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))
>
>         {
>             source.put(str.charAt(i), source.get(str.charAt(i) + 1));
>         }
>         else source.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
>     }
> ```

I can't even follow it. In addition to the above suggestion, ***always*** put braces for `if`, `for`, and `while` statements, no matter how long or short the statements are. Result:

```
    if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        continue;
    } else {
        if (source.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
            source.put(str.charAt(i), source.get(str.charAt(i) + 1));
        } else {
            source.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }
```

The `continue` can be removed by reversing the expression:

```
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        if (source.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
            source.put(str.charAt(i), source.get(str.charAt(i) + 1));
        } else {
            source.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }
```

and the `put` can be simplified with ternary:

```
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        source.put(str.charAt(i), source.containsKey(str.charAt(i)) ?
                source.get(str.charAt(i) + 1) :
                1);
    }
```

Also consider using JUnit 4 for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is the time and space complexity correct?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Take a look at edit, coming shortly.

Comment: Shouldn't space complexity be O(m) considering m is the size of "Sample" as I am only creating hash map of m size.

Comment: @HimanshuVerma Except you are creating it `n-m` times.

Comment: Yes. I think I need to look into how to calculate space-time complexity. I am having difficulties in calculating.